# mismatch input '$' expecting StringLiteral Inpath near 'inpath' in load statement

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I want to pass one path from spark submit command while loading data from one file to hive table.
I am trying pass that path using below code but its showing mismatch input '$' expecting StringLiteral Inpath near 'inpath' in load statement.

```
    obj hive_scala{
    def main(args:Array[String]){
    // creating sparksession
    val dbsession=HiveWareHouseSession.session(sparksession).build()
    dbsession.setDatabase("dbname")
    if(args.length<1){
    System.exit(1)
    }
    var a="load data inpath $args(0) into table tablename";
    val b=dbsession.executeUpdate(a)
    }
    }
```

then using below spark submit command:
        spark-submit --class classname projectjar  location(from here i need to load data into table)
can anyone suggest how should i pass this path using spark-submit and what code needs to change in scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the String to

```
var a=s"load data inpath ${args(0)} into table tablename";
```

The 's' prefix mark the String Interpolation. {}  should be used for expressions

Comment: Thanks alot @Artem Aliev  Aamir it's worked for me.                var a=s"load data inpath '${args(0)}'into table tablename";

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing some characters for using s interpolation:

```
 obj hive_scala {
    def main(args:Array[String]){
   // creating sparksession
   val dbsession = HiveWareHouseSession.session(sparksession).build()
   dbsession.setDatabase("dbname")
    if(args.length < 1){
      System.exit(1)
    }
   var a = s"load data inpath ${args(0)} into table tablename";
   val b = dbsession.executeUpdate(a)
 }
```

}